# malloc() memory corruption in C

Tags: c, memory, malloc, sha1, memory-corruption

malloc() is giving me an error in the following code. I used valgrind and still to no avail. I am a beginner at C and my team-mate and I were trying to implement the SHA1 algorithm but there is something which none of us can understand and have spent hours on this. This was the the function that had the error in it -

```
/*
 * Returns an array of chunks on the heap from the message
 */

static unsigned char **sha1_chunkify(const unsigned char *message, const uint64_t message_length)
{
    long num_chunks = message_length / 64;    //breaking it down into 64 byte chunks
    printf("%lu %ld\n", message_length, num_chunks);
    unsigned char **chunks = malloc (num_chunks * sizeof(*chunks)); //Error is coming over here

    for (int i = 0; i < num_chunks; i++) {
        chunks[i] = malloc (64 * sizeof(*chunks[i])); //Or sometimes over here.

        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            chunks[i][j] = message[64 * i + j];
        }
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Here is the gdb output at those lines -

```
117     printf("%lu %ld\n", message_length, num_chunks);
(gdb) 
1472 23
118     unsigned char **chunks = (unsigned char **) malloc (num_chunks * sizeof(*chunks));
(gdb) 
*** Error in `/home/username/Desktop/Project_VCS/a.out': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000060cac0 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a4bcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

And Valgrind shows the following -

```
3
mytry.c
==16688== Invalid write of size 1
==16688==    at 0x401EA6: append_zeroes (sha1.c:155)
==16688==    by 0x401F1D: sha1_pad (sha1.c:177)
==16688==    by 0x401FB7: sha1 (sha1.c:200)
==16688==    by 0x400C72: snap_file (snap.c:40)
==16688==    by 0x4012F7: snap (snap.c:143)
==16688==    by 0x401852: snap_all (snap.c:220)
==16688==    by 0x40222E: main (nako.c:24)
==16688==  Address 0x5220720 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,408 alloc'd
==16688==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16688==    by 0x401F7B: sha1 (sha1.c:195)
==16688==    by 0x400C72: snap_file (snap.c:40)
==16688==    by 0x4012F7: snap (snap.c:143)
==16688==    by 0x401852: snap_all (snap.c:220)
==16688==    by 0x40222E: main (nako.c:24)
==16688== 
==16688== Invalid write of size 1
==16688==    at 0x401E6A: append_msg_len (sha1.c:142)
==16688==    by 0x401F34: sha1_pad (sha1.c:179)
==16688==    by 0x401FB7: sha1 (sha1.c:200)
==16688==    by 0x400C72: snap_file (snap.c:40)
==16688==    by 0x4012F7: snap (snap.c:143)
==16688==    by 0x401852: snap_all (snap.c:220)
==16688==    by 0x40222E: main (nako.c:24)
==16688==  Address 0x5220758 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==16688== 
1472 23

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:277 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.

==16688==    at 0x38050BAC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x38050D06: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x3805B36A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x3805D2D7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x380216D4: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x380218A2: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x3809DC03: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==16688==    by 0x380AC87C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==16688==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16688==    by 0x401D94: sha1_chunkify (sha1.c:118)
==16688==    by 0x401FCA: sha1 (sha1.c:202)
==16688==    by 0x400C72: snap_file (snap.c:40)
==16688==    by 0x4012F7: snap (snap.c:143)
==16688==    by 0x401852: snap_all (snap.c:220)
==16688==    by 0x40222E: main (nako.c:24)
```

I have gone through several threads but the error still persists. I apologize if it has been asked before. I could not find the same. Thanking You in advance.

Here are the functions append_zeroes and append_msg_len -

```
/*
 * Pad the message with its length.
 * The input lengths are in bytes, while the padding, in accordance with
 * the SHA1 algorithm, is done in bits.
 */
static inline void append_msg_len(unsigned char *message,
                  uint64_t *message_length,
              uint64_t original_msglen)
{
    int shift = 56;
    while (shift >= 0) {
        /* Add the next 8 bits. */
         message[*message_length] = (8 * original_msglen >> shift) & 0xff;
         shift -= 8;
    *message_length += 1;
    }
}

/*
 * Appends enough zeroes until the message has just enough room for appending
 * the message length, i.e, length 448 mod 512
 */
static inline void append_zeroes(unsigned char *message, uint64_t *message_length)
{
    while (*message_length % 64 != 56) {
        message[*message_length] = (unsigned char) 0x00;
        *message_length += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The valgrind-output shows very clearly that the problem is not in the code you've posted, but rather in `append_zeroes()`.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place ... hunt down these *invalid writes* (if you look closely, `valgrind` tells you exactly that)

Comment: Every time you allocate memory, you must free it. I don't see any calls to the `free()` function.

Comment: @Mike: The function returns an array of `malloc()`ed pointers. I wouldn't expect the function itself `free()`ing them, that would likely be an error.

Comment: @Mike, returning some dynamically allocated object from a function is perfectly fine, the caller must free it later. The problem is not inside the code posted here.

Comment: this line: `long num_chunks = message_length / 64;` is a integer divide, so will result in num_chunks being 1 less than the actual number of chunks due to any fraction being truncated

Comment: the posted code contains the `magic` number 64.  Using `magic` numbers makes the code much more difficult to understand and will cause major headaches when maintenance is performed.   Strongly suggest using a enum or #define to create a meaningful name and using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: this line:`unsigned char **chunks = malloc (num_chunks * sizeof(*chunks));` is nonsense.  What is really needed is: `unsigned char **chunks = malloc (num_chunks * sizeof( char *));`

Comment: @user3629249: No, that line is perfectly fine.

Comment: this line: `chunks[i] = malloc (64 * sizeof(*chunks[i]));` should be similar to: `chunks[i] = malloc (64);`  (note the prior comment about using a meaningful name for 64)

Comment: this code block: `for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            chunks[i][j] = message[64 * i + j];
        }`  is not correct.   Suggest: `memcpy(&chunks[i][0], message[64*i, 64);`

Comment: @ken-y-n: My other function in the program makes sure that the length of the message is an exact multiple of 64 so that it will always give an exact positive integer in num_chunks, so there is no problem in that line as far as I can make out.

Comment: suggest replacing: `long num_chunks = message_length / 64` with: `long num_chunks = (message_length+63) / 64`

Comment: @user3629249 Why is the code block wrong - it is inefficient, but I cannot see a functional problem.

Comment: @DeathStocker Please also post your `append_zeros` code as that's was seems to muck up the allocation heap causing faults in the `sha1_chunkify` code.

Comment: @user3629249 see my comment to the answer below -- this might lose some data, but it doesn't cause the heap corruption.

Comment: I have added the function in the original post, which make sure to pad the message accordingly.

Comment: `sha1_chunkify()` alone mixes arithmetic of _4_ types of integer:  `uint64_t`, `int`, `long`, `size_t`.  An unexpected range conversion loss would be catastrophic and code does not check for that.  For debug, recommend adding `assert()` to insure conversions occur as expected.

Comment: in coding in C (or most any other language) never assume anything.

Comment: Thank you for the extra code; I think now the place to check is if the original `message` is long enough to cope with the additional padding; the valgrind output suggests it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this code:

```
long num_chunks = message_length / 64;    //breaking it down into 64 byte chunks
```

If we use `message_length` = 63, for instance, `num_chunks` becomes zero, which is obviously wrong. If you use instead:

```
long num_chunks = (message_length + 63) / 64;    //breaking it down into 64 byte chunks
```

You will get the right number of chunks, and hopefully the rest of your code will be well-behaved.

Comment: This is only a concern if message_length is *not* a multiple of 64 and would -- in this code -- only lead to some data loss, which would be wrong, but not causing the error asked about. The code in this function doesn't write beyond the end of the allocated space.

Comment: Assuming `message_length` is not always a multiple of 64, I suppose that other code (such as `append_zeros`) could calculate chunks correctly and try to use an unallocated block? But we are guessing without the `append_zeros` code.

Comment: Sure that's possible. There's quite some stack trace in the *invalid write* location, the problem could be anywhere...